# Check for a column in all tables and if column is present print the table name - kdb

Tags: kdb

We have 3 tables with below columns in our current namespace

```
q)t:([] a:`a`b`c; b:1 2 3);
q)s:([] a:`a`b`c; b:1 2 3);
q)z:([] z:`a`b`c; b:1 2 3);
```

Now we want to search and print all the tables which have column a.

```
Expected output: `a`s
```

I have two ugly solution which somewhat works

```
q){$[`a in cols x;x;]} each tables[];
q){(enlist x) where enlist(`a in cols x)}each tables[];
```

But looking for better optimal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be best to use the [each right (/:)](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/maps/#each-left-and-each-right) adverb with `in`:

```
q)tables[] where `a in/: cols each tables[]
`s`t
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is the sort of thing you would like to parameterise and use again something like the following projection may be of use to you:

```
f:{[t;c]c!t@/:where each flip(c,:())in/:cols each t}[tables[]];
```

This function produces the following output

```
q)f`a
a| s t
q)f`a`b
a| `s`t
b| `s`t`z
```

So it maps a column name to a list of tables containing that column. 
This sort of mapping can often be more advantageous than working with simple lists as it allows for quick, legible indexing.

```
q)coldict:f`a`b
q)coldict[`a]
`s`t
```